# Filtering a list and getting first N elements

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am noobie in python but I needed to plot some images from the dataset and I wanted to use list comprehension for this but didn't know how. So I used a `while` loop, but there also was a problem of accessing tuple containing labels with size (1080, ) and I got error message like this:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

So after I reshaped the tuple, everything was ok. My code:

```
i, j = 0, 0
y = np.reshape(Y_train_orig, (1080))
while (j < 5):
    if y[i] == 0 : 
        plt.imshow(X_train_orig[i])
        plt.show()
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

So I'm wondering if it really was nesessary to reshape it and if I could avoid using loops and use list comprehension instead. Would it be more effective than my `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting the code that generates `Y_train_orig` we cannot know its shape, or even if it is a `numpy.ndarray`, and so we cannot help you with the reshaping.

Regarding the main question: List comprehensions are not for conventional looping (though you *can* hack something together if you really want to), but only to collect results into a list, possibly applying some filter as well. You want to perform some action (plotting) multiple times, and so you should indeed use a `while` or a `for` loop.

For completeness, here's how I would write your loop, given that I do not know much about your variables:

```
count = 0
for y_i, x in zip(y, X_train_orig):
    if y_i == 0: 
        plt.imshow(x)
        plt.show()
        if count == 5:
            break
        count += 1
```